# emacs minor-mode failing upon call to require

Tags: minor-mode

I am making a minor mode that is split into a number of files.

In my `.emacs` I have done

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/bin/tika")
(require 'tika)
(tika-tools)
```

In `tika.el` resides the function

```
(defun tika-tools ()

   (require 'tika-hgstyle)

   (setq outline-minor-mode-highlight 'override)
   (tika-addhook-hgptn)
   (tika-outlhg-tyface))
```

The problem is that as soon as I run `emacs` I get

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (end-of-file "/home/hagbard/bin/tika/tika-hgstyle.el")")
  read(#<buffer  *load*-59131>)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-59131> nil "/home/hagbard/bin/tika/tika-hgstyle.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 13526
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/hagbard/bin/tika/tika-hgstyle.el" "/home/hagbard/bin/tika/tika-hgstyle.el" nil t)
  require(tika-hgstyle)
  tika-tools()
```

Comment: Have found that the problem was a missing closing parenthesis `)`.